# How to constraint values of an object in JSON schema?

Tags: json, jsonschema

I want to constrain my object values. In particular, only `string` and `array` (of string) types are allowed:

```
"myobject": {
  "string": "foo",
  "array": [
    "bar",
    "baz",
  ],
  "bool": true, // invalid
  "object": {}, // invalid
}
```

Object keys should be "free". I can't find a way to do this in JSON schema.

The following seems not working, it still allow `bool` and `object` value types:

```
"myobject": {
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "type": ["string", "array"]
  }
}
```

Comment: is this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35683723/json-schema-object-property-constraints

Comment: @Inga thanks for helping, but in that question, the key are "fixed". It's easy to define types for a fixed-keys object.

Answer (score 1):

If the keys are „free“ as you put it, you can use the `additionalProperties` keyword like this:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "additionalProperties": {
    "type": ["string", "array"]
  }
}
```